# Angular2 Ionic2 Native error deviceready did not fire within ms

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

Ionic2 Native Error: deviceready did not fire within 2000ms

**THIS CAUSES WHITE SCREEN - WHEN APP START!**

**Any Solution??**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

First make sure your plugins are listed in package.json, then do the following:

`ionic platform rm android`

`ionic platform add android`

I also had some issues with the splashscreen plugin causing a white screen on startup, so make sure the configuration is set in config.xml. For example:

`...
    <preference name="ShowSplashScreen" value="true"/>
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false"/> 
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="0"/>
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="false"/>
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="0"/>
    <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false"/>
    <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false"/>
    <preference name="SplashScreenBackgroundColor" value="0xFFFFFFFF"/>
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
...`

and hide it on device ready at src/app/app.component.ts

`...
    export class MyApp {
    constructor(platform: Platform) {
      platform.ready().then(() => {
        this.hideSplashScreen();
        StatusBar.styleDefault();
      });
    }
    hideSplashScreen() {
        if (Splashscreen) {
            Splashscreen.hide();
        }
    }
  }`

Answer (score 1):

You could do `ionic state reset`. This would remove all the plugins and build everything from the `cordovaPlugins` in package.json . Make sure you have everything in there. This would depend on whether you have used `ionic plugin` or `cordova plugin`.

And this command might be deprecated as `cordova` now supports this feature.

**edit**

You could use `ionic state save` to save all plugins to `package.json`